# google cloud classic vpn to onprem. Neeto to NAT to public IP space the internal network

Tags: google-cloud-networking, google-cloud-vpn, google-cloud-router

GCP Side
10.27.20.0/24 --> [public NAT] --> VPC Endpoint --> VPN TUNNEL <-- ONPREM Endpoint

I'm on the GCP side of this equation and need to NAT our 10.27.20.0/24 internal IP space to routable IP space because the ONPREM account is huge and doesn't want to chance overlap with other customers.

GCP doesn't seem to support this out of the box. Cloud NAT doesn't seem to allow manual usage of publicly routable IPs.

Can someone break down for me how to implement the [public NAT] part of this equation?

Thank you!

I've followed lots of paths, but am not sure which will lead to correct conclusion and don't know enough to gaffer this up myself.

Comment: If you are trying to NAT using a public IP address a VPN is not required. I would not implement your design. Get someone from your networking team to show you how to correctly route networks together.

Comment: VPN is required by customer as is the public IP NAT. Not my design. I wish I had a network team.